# Change color of a portion of a php form select option

Tags: javascript, css

I need to make a portion of the text in a form select option label a different color to help it stand out. Anything with a `()` needs to be red for example. Is this even remotely possible?

```
<select id="product" name="product" onchange="calculatetotal();">
    <option value="5">1-4 years ($5)</option>
    <option value="10">5-9 years ($10)</option>
    <option value="15">10+ years ($15)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you can't really style options this way, unless you implement your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I've made something for you, tested and runs on `Firefox 15.1` pretty well, but surely you'll have trouble for cross-browser : [**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/khN72/)

HTML

```
<select id="product" name="product" onchange="calculatetotal();">
    <option value="5" class="red">1-4 years</option>
    <option value="10" class="red">5-9 years</option>
    <option value="15" class="red">10+ years</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
option.red:nth-child(1):after{
    content: "($5)";
    color: red;
}

option.red:nth-child(2):after{
    content: "($10)";
    color: red;
}

option.red:nth-child(3):after{
    content: "($15)";
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Hopefully you do not support older browsers.

Comment: @epascarello and other browsers too, surprised just firefox supports but it's just how I do it..

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery, Try:

```
$("select option:contains('(')").css("color", "red");
```

Here's the example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="product" name="product" onchange="calculatetotal();">                   
    <option value="5">0-1 years</option>
    <option value="5">1-4 years ($5)</option>
    <option value="10">5-9 years ($10)</option>
    <option value="15">10+ years ($15)</option>
</select>


<script>
$("select option:contains('(')").css("color", "red");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Extending upon Mr. Alien's answer above:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    option:after{
    content: attr(data-price);
    color: red;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="product" name="product" onchange="calculatetotal();">                   
    <option value="0" data-price="">0-1 years</option>
    <option value="5" data-price=" ($5)">1-4 years</option>
    <option value="10" data-price=" ($10)">5-9 years</option>
    <option value="15" data-price=" ($15)">10+ years</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure you can make only what's inside the "()" red. You can make the first "(" black by just including it by default, but I haven't been able to make the last ")" black again while keeping the price red.

Good luck

Comment: I think the OP wants just the stuff in the parentheses to be red, not the whole option.

Comment: You cannot format anything inside the <option> tag. At least to the best of my knowledge. You would have to build a menu system to do that.

Comment: Bummer, this is perfect if only I can limit the red between the ()

Comment: You can combine this with Mr Alien's CSS solution above.

Comment: Sorry I was tied up in meetings at work all day yesterday. See my updated my answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to style the whole line, you can do that in CSS.

If you want to style only a portion of the text you can not do it. You would need to use a [custom control](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/06/20/create-a-custom-select-box-with-jquery/).